# Don't return any result if the precedent query has at least 1 result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have this query:

```
( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE type = 'word1' )
  UNION
( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE type = 'word2' ) // Run this query if there are no results with type = 1
```

Basically I would like to run the second query only if the first hasn't any results. is it possible?

Comment: How about having two queries and deciding if you need the second one in your program?

Comment: @Thilo: i do that now... but it's pretty bad

Comment: How is it bad? Should perform much better if most of the time the first query does return some data.

Comment: I would like to know anyway if there is a SQL solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIRST "PreCheck" query does a count of how many records ARE of type = 1.  After that, if the count is greater than 1, then return 1, otherwise return 2.

Now, THAT answer can be used in the join (which is always a single row via COUNT(*)) which will either have a 1 or 2 value.  THAT value will be the second value is the EQUALITY conditon.  So, if there IS an entry of 1, the result will be as if

WHERE t1.Type = 1

Thus never allowing any 2 in the test.  HOWEVER, if NO entries are found, it will have a value of 2 and thus create a WHERE clause of

WHERE t1.type = 2

```
select t1.* 
   from 
      ( select if( count(*) > 0, 1, 2 ) IncludeType
           from tbl t2
           where t2.type = 1 ) preCheck,
      tbl t1
   where 
      t1.type = preCheck.IncludeType
```

If there is an index on the "type" column, the first query should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: that's smart. I would include a LIMIT 1 on your first sub query so it's even faster

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
select * from tbl 
where type = 1 
union 
select * from tbl 
where type = 2 
and not exists( select * from tble where type = 1 )
```

but this probably won't perform as well as just doing it in your program

Answer (score 0):

It does the trick:

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl JOIN (SELECT min(type) min_type FROM tbl WHERE type between 1 and 2 ) on min_type = type
```

First, it selects the lesser of these two types, if any exists, and then oins this one number table to your table. It is actually a simple filter. You can use WHERE instead of JOIN, if you want.

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl WHERE (SELECT min(type) FROM tbl WHERE type between 1 and 2 ) = type
```